# How to use properties defined in XAML in the C# code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a `XAML` document with `C#` code-behind.

In the `C#` class I define some properties, that I can then set in `XAML`:

```
public partial class MyClass : ContentView
{
    public Color MyColor { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent()

        //Here I want to use the color
    }
}
```

```
<MyClass MyColor="Blue"/>
```

The problem is that the property is never set. When I try to use it, it still has its default value (White).

Same happens when I use `BindableProperties`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MyColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyColor), typeof(Color), typeof(MyClass), Colors.White);

public Color MyColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(MyColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyColorProperty, value);
}
```

How are you supposed to do this? I want to use the properties set on this element instance by `XAML`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, put breakpoint on "set" line of MyColor. Is that breakpoint hit? The c# code you show, is in MyClass.xaml.cs, right? And **when** do you try to use that color? Perhaps you are using it **before** the page that contains the `MyClass` element sets the color? So another breakpoint where you use the color, to make sure that is hit AFTER `MyColor set`.

Comment: you're not using binding, so BindableProperty probably isn't the issue.  It may be as simple as the property isn't initialized in the constructor

Comment: Any idea where they might be initialized? Thought they were initialized in `InitializeComponen()`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Breakpoints were a good idea. Have confirmed that the property is set after the constructor. The question now is where I can insert my logic and be sure that all properties have been set by `XAML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `OnHandlerChanged`. After some experiemnts, I can confirm that `XAML` properties have been set at this stage, and that it will be called each time.

In code, it would look like this:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();
    //Retrieve or use your properties
}
```

Another proposed solution (if you are using `ContentPage`) is the method `OnAppearing`.

**Edit:**

To further elaborate, this is what the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) have to say about `OnHandlerChanged`:

`HandlerChanged` is raised after the handler for a cross-platform control has been created. This event indicates that the native control that implements the cross-platform control is available, and all the property values set on the cross-platform control have been applied to the native control.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to picture c# code instead of xaml. The two are equivalent.

If the use of your component looked like:

```cs
var c = new MyClass();
c.MyColor = Color.Blue;
```

then what is value of MyColor during constructor?

Clearly, it is still White.

To see Blue, use MyColor in any method override. The most common one is `OnAppearing`:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // use MyColor here.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping they were set in `InitializeComponent`. Anyways, `OnAppearing` doesn't seem to exist for `ContentView`. Should I just use `ContentPage` instead? (Making a chart control)